# Cannot access django development server without ssl using chrome

Tags: django, google-chrome

I setup a clean django project with:

```
django-admin startproject newProject
cd newProject
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver

January 29, 2019 - 00:30:02 Django version 2.1.2, using settings
'unchained.settings' Starting development server at
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

And navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ with Google-Chrome (71.0.3578.98):

```
[29/Jan/2019 00:30:08] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.

[29/Jan/2019 00:30:08] code 400, message Bad request version ('ÊÊÀ+À/À,À0Ì©Ì¨À\x13À\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x00')
[29/Jan/2019 00:30:08] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

So, at some point in the past I activated SSL with a totally unrelated project. And for some strange reason, chrome now expects HTTPS. I could probably fix it by deleting the browser cache, but I don't really want to loose all the data that is in there.

How would you solve this?

Comment: it never entered my mind to think that this problem might be because of caching.. thanks for suggesting that as a possible solution in your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Django Development server only uses `Http` protocol instead of `Https`. Your site is being opened at  https://127.0.0.1:8000/ instead of  http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Go to `settings .py` and change

`SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False`

Comment: This does not help. The error remains. Chrome returns `This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Comment: Can you share your `settings.py` file?

Comment: You can create it yourself. Type `django-admin startproject newProject`. I think it is more of a Chrome issue. At some time in the past I activated SSL for a different project. Now Chrome expects SSL for this URL

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False` in my settings.py and Chrome still doesn't like it.  I agree that I think it's a Chrome issue, but I can't find a workaround...

Comment: I think it's somehow caching the URL you may have previously made. You could try clearing out Chrome. As a quick fix, I openned the site in an Incognito tab and it worked.

Comment: Agreed with @alj. 1) Set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False` and 2) open `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in Chrome incognito or clear Chrome cache and open in regular tab should fix it.